# Deep Learning and human voice modification

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm working on a pet project with my D&D friends. Let's say I have a dataset of orc voices (people talking like orcs, saying sentences in English but with intonations and phrasing of orcs), elf voices and dwarf voices. What kind of ML models should I use if I wanted to extract what makes a orc voice "orcish" and use those characteristics to modify my own voice (for instance, a sentence I record saying) to make it "orcish" ?

The final product would me ("my_sentence.wav", 'orc') -> ML model -> ("my_sentence_with_orc_accent.wav") ?

I still want to keep the phrasing of my voice, the intelligibility of the words, but blended with other characteristics to enhance it.

Could you point me to model names or concepts so I can look into resources ?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following paper:
"Improving Zero-shot Voice Style Transfer via Disentangled Representation Learning" (see https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.09420):

> "...Voice style transfer, also called voice conversion, seeks to
> modify one speaker's voice to generate speech as if it came from
> another (target) speaker."

Comment: Thank you. It is indeed the kind of concepts we would like to try.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! We are trying to build a permanent 
repository of high-quality statistical information in the form 
of questions & answers. Thus, we're wary of link-only answers, 
due to link rot. Can you edit to include a 
summary of the information at the link, in case it goes dead?